# Dismissing Notification on one device persists on other devices

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-watch, notifications

I don't recall the exact OS version I had on my iPhone and Watch, but starting with a recent update it seems like if I clear/dismiss a notification on my iPhone, it **does not** clear on my Watch. I'm pretty sure it used to clear everywhere, as I don't recall seeing very old notifications on my watch like I do now.

I don't recall changing any settings, but perhaps I did and forgot.

**In general, is there a way where dismissing notifications on one device dismisses it on all linked devices?**

Comment: I have watchOS 6.1 and iOS 13.2.2 and it clears from all devices for me.  Are you on the most recent OS's?

Comment: @fsb - yes, I am on the latest os for both the phone and watch

Comment: Do you have Notifications set to mirror your iPhone in the Watch app?

Comment: @fsb - yes, all of them are set to mirror the iphone